# How to skip iteration in *ngFor loop without drawing in the view an empty item when *ngIf returns false

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular-ng-if

Im trying to draw in a grid a set of items that meet a condition, but an iteration does not meet the condition, and empty grid item is still drawn in the view. How do I stop the *ngFor (or whatever is responsible) from drawing

```
<div class="grid main" *ngIf="blogPosts$ | async as blogPosts">
<div class="tile" *ngFor="let blogPost of blogPosts.items">
    <div *ngIf="blogPost.fields.category == this.catLink.getCat()">
        <div (click)="catLink.setCat(blogPost.fields.category)" 
           [routerLink]="['/article', blogPost.sys.id]" >
            <img width="375" height="250" [src]="blogPost.fields.featuredImage.fields.file.url" alt="">
            <div class="title"><span>{{ blogPost.fields.title }}</span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Im using content from contentful headless CMS

Comment: An empty object is still an existing object, I will suggest that you fix your service or function to not send empty objects to avoid this. It is hard to see where the problem is if you only share your HTML file, please also share your `.ts` file.

Comment: Why don't you apply . filter on the result side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping in mind that the better solution would be to filter your data in code rather than in the template, this might help.

I am guessing that the empty element is the `div` with a class of tile. It is always printed because you iterate on a `div`, which inserts an element in the DOM. You also print a `div` with the nested NgIf.

Try using `<ng-container>` instead and print only if the condition is met.

```
<div class="grid main" *ngIf="blogPosts$ | async as blogPosts">

    <ng-container *ngFor="let blogPost of blogPosts.items">
        <ng-container *ngIf="blogPost.fields.category == this.catLink.getCat()">
            <div class="tile">
                <div>
                    <div (click)="catLink.setCat(blogPost.fields.category)" 
           [routerLink]="['/article', blogPost.sys.id]" >
                        <img width="375" height="250" [src]="blogPost.fields.featuredImage.fields.file.url" alt="">
                    <div class="title"><span>{{ blogPost.fields.title }}</span></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

Comment: This works beautifully, thanks!
But should i always put ngFor and ngIf inside an ng-container tag?

Comment: Not always, but it is useful as a structure to host a structural directive when you do not want to produce an HTML element. When you put an NgIf on a div, it will insert a div in the DOM when the condition is true. With ng-container no element is inserted.